# Why can't I upload a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to upload a photo using Node.js. But when I upload, it shows this error:

**Cannnot read property file of undefined**

**at C:\new\file.js:13:26**

Looks like I'm doing something wrong with `req.files.file.name` which I don't understand. What can be the issue?

Here's the code:

**file.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(multer({dest: '/files/'}).single('file'));
app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/' + '/index.html')
});
app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.files.file.name);
    console.log(req.files.file.path);
    console.log(req.files.file.type);
    var file = __dirname + '/' + req.files.file.name;
    fs.readFile(req.files.file.name, function (err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error reading");
            } else {
                response = {
                    message: 'file uploaded successfully',
                    filename: req.files.file.name
                };
            }
            console.log(response);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    });
});
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("The server is running at http://%s:%s ", host, port);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/file_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `console.log(req.files);` to home in on the null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do, which works fine:

```
var uploadPath = 'public/uploads/';
var upload = multer({dest: uploadPath});

router.post('/image', upload.single('thePhoto'), function (req, res) {
    var uploadedFile = uploadPath + req.file.filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be caused because you have already added multer in app.use() which parses all the data before the control goes to post method. So I think you should either use fs or multer but not both.